# Set title text attributes for landscape navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

Is there a way to set the title text attributes for a navigation bar in landscape mode using the appearance API?

On iPhone (except iPhone 6 Plus) the navigation bar shrinks in size in landscape.  I want to switch to a smaller font in this state but I'm not sure how to detect this change especially when the iPhone 6 Plus keeps the navigation bar the same size in landscape mode.